# Add App groups without adding a developer account on Xcode?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, apple-developer-account

I have a development provision profile and development certificate. Using manual signIn I build the application. App Groups enabled on my profile. In capabilities added app groups not displaying and I try to add app groups it showing no account configured error. Is it possible to use app groups with provision profiles and development certificates?
[image]

Comment: I have tried using a development certificate, I added app group  capability successfully.

Comment: @childrenOurFuture I enabled app groups on our provision profile. Using those profiles in Xcode. But inside capability added app groups are not visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to the Entitlements file by adding the following key.

```
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>App Group Identifier</string>
</array>
```

This will only work if your provisioning profile already supports the groups you're adding. If you want to add an app group to the provisioning profile, you need to do it from the Apple Developer website.

Answer (score 1):

I write here, I need post a picture.
Are you check here?[image]
once you have added the app-group capability, you won't find it in the + button list

Then below is the develop center page, have you check this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: In provision profile app groups enabled. but not showing in capability

Comment: It really look strange, I new a project without a profile or team, I can find the app group item in + button list ,and I can add it.